# where i need to run ionic command ? And please refer some good video to learn ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

i want to learn ionic framework. I saw one video for beginners but i am not getting where i need to run ionic command ?
Which command do I need to use to build a ionic project ?
And please refer some good video to learn ionic framework.

Comment: what is the IDE platform you use?

Comment: Follow this link: http://mcgivery.com/100-ionic-framework-resources/

Comment: [this](https://blog.nraboy.com/tag/ionic/) is ultimate help..!

Comment: Questions seeking recommended resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is, If you want to learn ionic, dont use any IDE. Learn from commands.

start using these docs [start ionic](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

refer to this [forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/) if you have any questions

start doing ionic apps using [api](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/) and [css](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/) provided by Ionic.

All the best

Comment: is angular js is better than ionic framework  for mobile app development?

Comment: Angularjs is a javascript framework and ionic is sdk for hybrid app development which uses angularjs. Both can not be compared and you have to use both.

Comment: @Swati angularjs is for scripting and ionic is a framework.. you have to use a language to do something in a framework. Here in Ionic framework which is based on cordova, you will use angularJS